# Gerrit & Jenkins pipeline newest changes

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I have a Jenkins and a Gerrit running to validate my code. Jenkins has the gerrit trigger plugin. Gerrit should trigger a declarative pipeline which gets the newest changes and build it.

this works: 
git fetch http://localhost:8081/PipelinePart1 refs/changes/87/387/1 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD

but is there a way to get always the newest changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the $GERRIT_REFSPEC build parameter which, in your case, will be equal to "refs/changes/87/387/1". See the following image for reference:

[image: GERRIT_REFSPEC]

Comment: how can I use it in the Pipeline?

Comment: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/$GERRIT_REFSPEC:refs/remotes/origin/$GERRIT_REFSPEC --prune" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/$GERRIT_REFSPEC

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ignor the last post :D
I just tested it with a manual build.... 
I forgot, that i need to do it over Gerrit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working configuration I am using

[image]